# Connect by ssh without password (rpm installation)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rpm

I have install my own rpm-package on local machine. During installation I should test ssh connection without password.

rpm package have a folder, which contain software and scripts.

On **%post** section of rpm I call one of my script (*script1*) and it create new user ( will call it "user1", for example ) by follow command:

```
groupadd user1
adduser -g user1 -c "sshuser" user1  >/dev/null
```

After this, I call another script (*script2*), which contain follow:

```
su -c "$0" user1
echo "y" | ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-keyscan -H localhost
```

But when installation finished, I can't do

```
su user1
ssh localhost
```

without password.
Also I can't login without password if I exec manually

```
su user1
echo "y" | ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub > $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But if I remove dsa-keys before:

```
su user1
rm -f ~/.ssh/{id_dsa*,authorized*}
ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub > $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I can use

```
ssh localhost
```

without problem.

Also, If I run *script1* and *script2* manually I can use ssh successfully.

What I do wrong?

Also I checked permission of all files in $HOME/.ssh

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user1 root 4096 Apr 17 11:44 .
drwx------. 5 user1 user1 4096 Apr 17 11:41 ..
-rw-------. 1 user1 user1 604 Apr 17 11:44 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 user1 user1 672 Apr 17 11:44 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 uesr1 user1 604 Apr 17 11:44 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------. 1 user1 user1 884 Apr 17 11:44 known_hosts
-rw-------. 1 user1 user1 884 Apr 17 11:44 known_hosts.old
```

**Update**:

```
cat /var/logs/messages | grep ssh
Apr 17 12:29:15 tivoli kernel: type=1400 audit(1429262955.308:57): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=9711 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev=dm-0 ino=1187196 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=file
```

But permission still

```
-rw-------. 1 user1 user1 604 Apr 17 11:44 authorized_keys
```

**Update2**:
Also help to remove only authorized_keys and recreate it:

```
rm -f $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: You need the public key on the remote host in authorized_keys, not on your localhost.

Comment: @mistapink I trying to connect by ssh to localhost, so I must add my public key to my authorized_keys on localhost

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. Did you check the logs? It may give you a hint, why the authentication fails (loading wrong key etc.)

Comment: I found next:
Apr 17 12:29:15 tivoli kernel: type=1400 audit(1429262955.308:57): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=9711 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev=dm-0 ino=1187196 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=file
so why, if file owned by user and have permission 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding follow line after creating user:

```
mkdir /home/user1/.ssh
restorecon -R -v /home/user1/.ssh
```

Now *script1* look like this:

```
groupadd user1
adduser -g user1 -c "sshuser" user1  >/dev/null
mkdir /home/user1/.ssh
restorecon -R -v /home/user1/.ssh
```